# How to create Enquiry popup form in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

As per my requirement I need to include enquiry popup form in my project so far I tried this.

Placed this basic HTML form in one of my `.phtml` page.

```
<div id="popup">
<!-- Popup Div Starts Here -->
<div id="popupContact">
<!-- Contact Us Form -->
<form action="#" id="form" method="post" name="form">
<img id="close" src="images/3.png" onclick ="div_hide()">
<h2>Contact Us</h2>
<hr>
<label id="name">Name<input name="name" type="text"></label>
<label id="phno">Phone Number<input name="phno" type="text"></label>
<label id="email">Email<input name="email" type="text"></label>
<label id="msg">Enquiry<textarea name="message"></textarea></label>
<a href="javascript:%20check_empty()" id="submit">Submit</a>
</form>
</div>
<!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
</div>
<!-- Display Popup Button -->
<h1>Click Button To Popup Form Using Javascript</h1>
<button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button>
```

and this is the js file included using page.xml

```
// Validating Empty Field
function check_empty() {
if (document.getElementById('name').value == "" || document.getElementById('email').value == "" || document.getElementById('msg').value == "") {
alert("Fill All Fields !");
} else {
document.getElementById('form').submit();
alert("Form Submitted Successfully...");
}
}
//Function To Display Popup
function div_show() {
document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
}
//Function to Hide Popup
function div_hide(){
document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "none";
}
```

and a `.css` file also included using `page.xml`

but doing this crashed my page.Please help me in solving this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you use the same code??If so please change the `abc` to `popup` here

**js file**

```
function div_show() {
    document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
    }
    //Function to Hide Popup
    function div_hide(){
    document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "none";
    }
```

or change

**HTML File** `id="abc"` here `<div id="popup">`

Comment: How stupid I am this simple thing ruining me from morning thanks :)